# error with cors when trying to send data from a session start, only the token is received as a response

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a section start, and it throws me the following error

```js
const submit = (e) => {
    axios.post("http://back-reserva.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/login", e).then(res => console.log(res))
  }
```

Error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://back-reserva.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/login' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:  Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not
> allowed for a preflight request. Failed to load resource:
> net::ERR_FAILED xhr.js:151 Uncaught (in promise)  AxiosError code:
> "ERR_NETWORK" config :  {transitional: {…}, transformRequest:
> Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
> message :  "Network Error" name :  "AxiosError"

The api is already using CORS, even so I keep getting that error.

Comment: *Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.* is your backend redirecting OPTIONS requests? Your frontend seems to think so

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean, I just started programming

Comment: The error states that the preflight request was redirected, which is not allowed - without specific details of the server code and setup it's hard to tell you what you did wrong **on the server**